count number of 1's in a bus using verilog. Having issue in the simulation (not getting proper output)
I am writing a verilog code to count the number of 1's in a bus. I have written a code which i think will do the job , but when i am simulating it on EDA playgrounds I am not getting the desired output.
here is the verilog code-
module count_1 #( parameter n =8)( 
  input [n-1:0] in,
  output reg[$clog2(n):0] out 
);
  

  integer i;

  always @(in) begin 
    for (i=0;i<8;i=i+1) begin
      if (in[i] == 1'b1)
         out <= out + 1'b1;
      else 
        out<=out;
    end
  end       
endmodule

here is the testbench-
module tb;
  parameter n=8;
  reg [n-1:0] in;
  wire [$clog2(n):0] out;
  count_1 dut (.in(in) , .out(out));
  initial begin
    in = 8'b1001_0110;
    #10;
    in = 8'b1101_1110;
    #10;
    in = 8'b1001_0111;
    #10;
    in = 8'b1111_0110;
    #10;
    in = 8'b1100_0110;
    #10;
  end
    
  
 initial begin
    $dumpfile("dump.vcd");
    $dumpvars();
  end
  
  
  initial begin
    #200;
    $finish();
  end
endmodule

In the simulation I don't see the integer i changing values in the for loop, and I think this could be the reason for not getting the output. Is there anything I could do?
here is the EDA Playgrounds link-
https://www.edaplayground.com/x/FxBp
